# MySQL foreign key to another foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

The idea is quite simple: i have three (or more) tables

```
- master_tbl (id, something, somethingelse)
- tbl2 (id, ....)
- tbl3 (id, ....)
```

Now what i want is a foreign key relationship, such as tbl3.id would point to tbl2.id and tbl2.id would point to master_tbl.id - all foreign keys are `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`. What I'll get from this is that when I delete a record from tbl2, its tbl3 equivalent will get erased as well, but not master_tbl. When I delete a record from master_tbl, all three tables get erased.

When I try to create the foreign key on tbl3.id->tbl2.id, I get mysql error 150 - can't create table (the tbl2.id->master_tbl.id is already created).
My MySQL version is `5.1.46`. Any ideas why this might be?

**EDIT: table definitions**
smf_members aka master_table

```
-- Table "smf_members" DDL

CREATE TABLE `smf_members` (
  `id_member` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date_registered` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `posts` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_group` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lngfile` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_login` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `real_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `instant_messages` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unread_messages` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `new_pm` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `buddy_list` text NOT NULL,
  `pm_ignore_list` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pm_prefs` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mod_prefs` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message_labels` text NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `openid_uri` text NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `personal_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01',
  `website_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `icq` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `aim` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yim` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `msn` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hide_email` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `show_online` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `time_format` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `signature` text NOT NULL,
  `time_offset` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pm_email_notify` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `karma_bad` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `karma_good` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usertitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `notify_announcements` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `notify_regularity` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `notify_send_body` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notify_types` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `member_ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `member_ip2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `secret_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `secret_answer` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_theme` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_activated` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `validation_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_msg_last_visit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `additional_groups` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `smiley_set` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_post_group` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_time_logged_in` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `password_salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ignore_boards` text NOT NULL,
  `warning` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `passwd_flood` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pm_receive_from` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_member`),
  KEY `member_name` (`member_name`),
  KEY `real_name` (`real_name`),
  KEY `date_registered` (`date_registered`),
  KEY `id_group` (`id_group`),
  KEY `birthdate` (`birthdate`),
  KEY `posts` (`posts`),
  KEY `last_login` (`last_login`),
  KEY `lngfile` (`lngfile`(30)),
  KEY `id_post_group` (`id_post_group`),
  KEY `warning` (`warning`),
  KEY `total_time_logged_in` (`total_time_logged_in`),
  KEY `id_theme` (`id_theme`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

cyp_users aka tbl2

```
-- Table "cyp_users" DDL

CREATE TABLE `cyp_users` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unregistered',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cyp_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `smf_members` (`id_member`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

cyp_vip_users aka tbl3

```
-- Table "cyp_vip_users" DDL

CREATE TABLE `cyp_vip_users` (
  `id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `od` date NOT NULL,
  `do` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please post the script you are using. What you are trying to do is a core requirement for *any* database server. The error must be in your script.

Comment: I'm trying to do this through Navicat MySQL client, but I'll at least post the table definitions.

Comment: There's no foreign key from tbl3 to tbl2. I assume you forgot to post that part.

Comment: No, I didn't, that's the foreign key I can't create and this is why I post this question :-) This is the table WITHOUT the desired fk.

Comment: and why would you create tbl2 who's primary key is the foreign key into tbl1? Further, the ID of tbl3 is SIGNED io UNSIGNED. Perhaps that's related to your problem.

Comment: Of course, that solved it, I don't know how I didn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: As this *is* a Q&A site, I've written the solution into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ID's` of `tbl2` and `tbl3` are different types.
Foreign Keys need to be of the same type.

- tbl2.ID is `UNSIGNED`
- tbl3.ID is `SIGNED`